# How to prove the partial sum of sequence $\{\sin(j)\}$ is bounded?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

How to prove the partial sum of sequence $\{\sin(j)\}$ is bounded? How to show this by using $\sin x+\sin y=2\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}?$

Comment: Are $j$ the positive integers?  In other words, is the sequence
$$\sin 1, \sin 2, \sin 3, \dots?$$
If so, you can just write
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin 1 + \sin 2 + \cdots + \sin n &= \text{Im}(e^i + e^{2i} + \cdots + e^{ni}) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{(n+1)i} - 1}{e^i - 1}\right) \\
&\le \left|\frac{e^{(n+1)i} - 1}{e^i - 1}\right| \le \frac{|e^{(n+1)i}| + 1}{|e^i - 1|} = \frac{2}{|e^i - 1|}.
\end{align*}
$$

$\frac{2}{|e^i - 1|}$ is a constant, so this shows that the partial sums are bounded.

Comment: Yes, j is 1,2,3,... positive integers

Comment: I really like your method. But why the last numerator is 2?

Comment: I terribly misunderstood this question, sorry!. To address the numerator being 2, $e^{(n+1)i}$ has modulus 1.

Comment: @Aldoggen No problem. Any reference? I still don't know why $|e^{(n+1)i}|$=1

Comment: @JosephCamacho shouldn't be $ \text{Im}\left(\frac{\large e^i\times(e^{(n+1)i} - 1)}{e^i - 1}\right)$?

Comment: @Mariana we can write a complex number $a+bi$ as $re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ is the modulus and $\theta$ is the argument. You can read about this on wikipedia, it's basic knowledge about complex numbers. In that expression, $r=1$. The "absolute value" is equivalent to taking the modulus of the expression.

Comment: @Aldoggen yes, I remember now. Thank you!

Comment: I got sin1+sin2+...sinn=Im($\frac{e^i (e^{ni}-1)}{e^i-1}$)

Comment: @Soheil -- Almost.  Mariana has it right in the comment above.  But this has the same imaginary part as what I wrote.